# How to Run all feature files using serenity cucumber

Tags: cucumber, bdd, serenity-bdd

I am new to serenity BDD and  I want serenity Runner class to run all the feature file present under Feature folder in a single instance of browser, instead of opening and closing for all the features.
Currently I have 3 feature files and only one scenario in each feature file. But i want to execute all the scenarios in a single launched browser.

Your reply would help me moving next step!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xrM1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me when I use Screenplay, haven't tried with cucumber yet

```
serenity.restart.browser.for.each=never
```

Put it in serenity.properties file.